# Headset position always returns zero in Oculus Quest with Unity and Oculus SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I am using the Oculus Quest with Unity 2018.4.22f1 and Oculus SDK. Moving into my application works well. But every time I want to get the position of the headset, the vector zero is returned.

I tried these solutions :

```
OVRPose tracker = OVRManager.tracker.GetPose();
return tracker.position;
```

And

```
GameObject camera = GameObject.Find("OVRCameraRig");
return camera.transform.position;
```

This is position tracking setup:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to get the headset position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I want to get the headset's position, I am using the `transform.position` of the *CenterEyeAnchor* which is inside `OVRPlayerController/OVRCameraRig/TrackingSpace`.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class YourScriptNameHere : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject centerEye;
    Vector3 headsetPos;

    void Start(){
        centerEye = GameObject.Find("CenterEyeAnchor");
    }

    void Update(){
        headsetPos = centerEye.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!
The exact code est `centerEye = GameObject.Find("CenterEyeAnchor");` with a capital for `Find`.

Comment: Works well on Oculus Quest 2! I wonder why `OVRManager.tracker.GetPose();` is not working though.

Comment: Great! Please consider to upvote if you found this useful

Comment: I also just wanted to ask where did you put this script so that it gets triggered? I'm having the same issue, and I tried to attach the script to the center eye anchor object which you described the path above, but it didn't work. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Ahh, been a while since I last used Unity, but if I remember correctly it should work on all objects, what's not working for you? Perhaps you're not using the `OVRCameraRig` prefab?